# Diagnosing drush sql-sync problem

Tags: drush

Broadly, I'm having problems running drush sql-sync so that I can get a local copy of my dev database. I was getting an "The external command could not be executed due to an application error ... code: 255)" type thing.

To diagnose the problem more specifically, I ran *drush @local sql-conf* and got

```
 Array
    (
        [driver] => mysql
        [database] => soa
        [username] => drupaluser
        [host] => 127.0.0.1
        [port] => 33066
    )
```

When I then ran *drush @dev sql-conf* I got

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Running *drush @dev sql-conf -s* results in

```
Simulating backend invoke: ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no git@dev.sub.mysite.com 'drush  --invoke --simulate --root=/var/www/dev --uri=http://default  sql-conf   --site=sub --env=dev 2>&1' 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Permission denied (publickey,password).

This means the issue isn't with Drush, it's that the server that matches up to your @dev alias doesn't have your SSH public key set up to allow you access. Either your public key hasn't been added to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file or the permissions on that file (or the ~/.ssh/ directory) have the wrong settings.

Comment: Thank you! My id_rsa.pub was definitely copied into autorized_keys...Actually turned out I had rewritten ~/.ssh/config somehow!  Cleaned that up and in business.